# No plugin found for prefix 'sonar' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I'm getting this error:

> No plugin found for prefix 'sonar' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.codehaus.mojo, org.apache.maven.plugins] available from the repositories

I have added all plugins in my local, but it's still showing the same issue.

Comment: Please show your `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have pluginGroups in your settings.xml?

You can find the document from [SonarQube](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven)

And double check if you define all your plugins in  section

Answer (score 1):

Since the link posted in the other answer is outdated: The current documentation can be found here https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/

tl;dr:
Use this snippet in your `settings.xml`:

```
<settings>
    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `SonarQube` can't find or locate the libraries it needs. From your maven command `mvn sonar:sonar`, you should be able to see a lot of warnings generated. Analyze them and clear them incrementally i.e get the libraries it can't find, run the command again, and repeat.

I did that, and it worked.